# Proper way of of using ini_set()

Tags: php, error-handling

What's the proper way to use PHP `ini_set()` for **error_reporting**? Is it by using quotes:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL');
```

or without quotes:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

When I use the one with quotes, my site_errors.log file doesn't get populated. But when I use the one *without* quotes my site_errors.log file gets updated just fine. Here's what my php file looks like:

```
// my php file
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', 'On');
ini_set('error_log', 'site_errors.log');
```

Comment: How is this a question when you have no problem and have given yourself the answer already :)?

Comment: The reason: E_ALL is a PHP constant and therefore has to be written without the quotes.

Comment: Why not to use `error_reporting()` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without quotes. `E_ALL` is a pre-defined PHP constant, essentially the result of

```
define('E_ALL', some_value_here);
```

Once you put quotes around it, it's no longer a constant and PHP treats it as a plain string.

try this:

```
$x = E_ALL; // no quotes
$y = 'E_ALL'; // with quotes
echo "without: $x   with: $y";
```

The "without" version will will be a number (2^31-1), while the "with" version will be the literal text `E_ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

It is *without* the quotes, because `E_ALL`is a [predefined constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).